# Backbone.Js Sending Data with destroy()

Tags: backbone.js

I've got a basic social networking concept: Friend Requests.

Each friend request can either be accepted or declined, either action should result in the friend request being removed from the collection and deleted from the server.

I'm able to use `model.destroy()` to issue the `DELETE` request to the server and also remove the item from the FriendRequests collection.  But I need to send some additional data to the server about whether the Request was accepted or declined. `?accepted=true|false`

How do I do send additional data allong with `Destroy()` - or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Sounds like two different operations - an update then a delete.

Comment: I don't really need to update the friend request, I just need to be able to carry out different action depending on whether it was accepted or rejected

Comment: Understood, but these are just basic crud operations - delete doesn't convey additional information - it sounds like you need to update a state to be able to perform some logic when the delete happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @kinakuta that this is not a standard DELETE. Consider doing a PUT to `/friend-request/42/accept` or `/friend-request/42/decline`. Another option would be to do a standard update/PUT but on the server take the appropriate action when the `accepted` flag is provided during an update. You may also want to implement "soft delete" for your server side database records where the friend request doesn't actually get deleted but has its "status" attribute changed to the appropriate lifecycle value. Could be one of "pending", "declined", "accepted", etc. You may want to store additional metadata like a timestamp when the request was accepted, which could be interesting for reporting/analysis. If you delete the record, there's no convenient place to store that metadata.

Comment: This would have been a good comment, but NOT an answer. Didn't answer the actual question, even if what the OP did was not right in terms of coding.